# PHP srand() on different servers

Tags: php, random, srand

I'm using srand() to fix my randomize functions for the application. E.g. for srand(1) I get one set of random items from the array, and for srand(2) - another one.

I noticed that on my local machine and on the server these sets are different.

Is there a way to make them the same? The important part of my app is that srand(1) and srand(2) should produced constant results.

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php#102636

Comment: Note that the result may vary depending on the PHP version: https://3v4l.org/YPvpH

Comment: You could try using `mt_rand()` and `mt_srand()` instead, although [you still might get different results in some circumstances](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#refsect1-function.mt-rand-changelog). I think the only alternative is to code your own PRNG.